# Is it possible to parse a text file containing XML-like string using XmlSlurper in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have a method `readFileContent` which will take an XML file as an input and read the content of the XML file and then outputs a String of XML-like data.

Now, this XML-like String will be the input parameter of another method `extractActualData` that in turn will parse the XML-like String and produce the actual data as output.

My question is: Is it possible to parse a text file containing XML-like string using `XmlSlurper` in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in the class called[`XmlSlurper.parseText(String str)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parseText-java.lang.String-) where you pass a String containing XML body and you can process the result, something like:

```
def text = '''
    <list>
        <technology>
            <name>Groovy</name>
        </technology>
    </list>
'''

def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)

assert list instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
assert list.technology.name == 'Groovy'
```

*Source: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html*

You can use exact same method inside your `extractActualData` method.